# Clarifying how strings work as arguments in a function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance

I have already found a solution to my issue, at least for now, but I wonder if there are better ways, and also what the actual logic is.
I am learning Python for financial applications. I have learned how to request data for a single or multiple quotes through pandas_datareader. Today I tried to turn the process to a function.

For a single quote (let's say Apple) the code goes like this:

```
stock_data = pandas_datareader.DataReader('AAPL', data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2000-1-1')
```

I wanted to turn this to a function where you can pass the stock's symbol as an argument and get the stock's data e.g. :

```
def stock(x):
     stock_data = pandas_datareader.DataReader(x, data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2000-1-1')
     print(stock_data)
```

The rationale being that `stock('AAPL')` would return Apple's data, `stock(FB)` would do the same for FB and so on.

I found out it doesn't work this way and I wonder how do you tell the function that the argument it should expect is a string?

For now this is how I worked around it, but I didn't really follow a particular logic, I just kept trying things:

```
def stock(x):
    stock_data = pandas_datareader.DataReader(str(x), data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2000-1-1')
    print(stock_data)
```

The way I understand this works is that in line 2 I tell it to take x convert it to a string and move from there, so when I finally write `stock('AAPL')` it works as expected. I guess my question is do I always need to convert the argument to a string? Why can't x, as an argument, be anything, including a string?

Comment: So `stock['AAPL']` did not work in your first try at the function? What was the error message or output?

Comment: @rcriii  I must have mistyped something because I kept getting an error which I can't recall but now it works just fine. That's weird.

def price(x):
    pr = wb.DataReader(x, data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2000-1-1')
    print(pr)

price('AAPL') now works properly.

Comment: Glad it is working. In the future, it is good to copy the command you typed and the traceback into your question. Sometimes just seeing it in a different context will help you spot the error yourself. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

stock(FB) didnt work because its not in string format, FB isnt defined yet.Python will throw an error like : NameError: name 'a' is not defined
it should be stock("FB").
here we are passing "FB" as a string
or you could do

```
x = "FB"
stock(x)
```

you have to change the format to string otherwise python will consider it as an object which isnt defined yet.

Comment: Τhis makes sense and it is something I already tried. But I would prefer to pass the argument immediately without having to assign it to a variable first. The solution I found seems to allow me to work this way, instead of having to change x every time I just call the function and put the stock symbol as argument. 
Here is what I don't understand. As you correctly say FB is undefined but why 'FB' is still undefined? I mean even with quotes. Shouldn't the function understand that I am passing a string?

Comment: could you please tell me how are you passing the argument? Are you doing it manually or you there is someother code to do that ?

Comment: def stock():
    stock_data = pandas_datareader.DataReader(input("Enter: "), data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2000-1-1')
    print(stock_data)   
if its manually then this should work

Comment: I am doing it manually and now it seems to work. I can't even tell what the problem was, and I wasted all day trying to figure it out.

def price(x): pr = pandas_datareader.DataReader(x, data_source = 'yahoo', start = '2000-1-1') print(pr) price('AAPL')